# Bot send dynamically created, downloadable CSV using Microsoft Bot Framework (C#)

Tags: c#, botframework, dynamically-generated, slack

Goal: Dynamically create a CSV file with information from a Sql Server query (don't want to save the file) and send it to the user in a bot response on Slack. The user clicks on the link to download the file to their computer.

I have created the file information in a MemoryStream, but am having trouble sending it in the bot response. This is my C# pseudocode and code inspired by [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-add-media-attachments):

```
public async Task useSelectedUPC(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> item)
    {
        var upc = await item;

        // use upc to query sql server and obtain information
        // use that information to create a MemoryStream result in the format of a csv file

        reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>()
                {
                    new Attachment()
                    {
                        ContentType = "text/csv",
                        Content = $"data:text/csv; base 64, {Convert.ToBase64String(result.ToArray())}",
                        Name = "sample.csv"
                    }
                };
        reply.Text = "Results: ";
        await context.PostAsync(reply);
    }
```

I've also tried

```
Content = result,
```

and

```
Content = result.ToArray(),
```

and

```
Content = "hello",
```

and

```
Content = Convert.ToBase64String(result.toArray()),
```

I even tried changing the ContentType and name to be "text/plain".

But all I see in the Bot Framework Channel Emulator is *[File of type 'text/csv']* and no link. In Slack, nothing appears besides the attachment's text.

The Microsoft Bot Framework [Attachment Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.attachment?view=botbuilder-3.8) is vague about acceptable content. **What Attachment content is acceptable and how can I translate the MemoryStream result into an acceptable format?**

Comment: Can you add details about your 'result' object? But I'm not sure that you can pass csv file

Comment: Try sending $"data:text/csv; base 64, {Convert.ToBase64String(result.ToArray())}", in the ContentUrl property instead of in the Content one. Let me know if that works

Comment: Sending $"data:text/csv; base 64, {Convert.ToBase64String(result.ToArray())}", in the ContentUrl property results in a response with a link in Bot Framework Channel Emulator! But when I try to click on the link, a pop up opens saying "You'll need a new app to open this data" with an unclickable ok button. My computer is able to open csv files regularly. In Slack, none of the message appears (no "Results" and no link). I believe the conversion to a base64 string is valid because when put into online converters, it responds with valid text that can be opened by Google Sheets.

Comment: 'Result' details: https://gist.github.com/jcsands123/fd9b0947d019fefc80f47ec37eb10f47

Answer (score 0):

To use Slack-specific message functionality, you need to configure a JSON object containing your attachments, and place it in the `channelData` property of your Activity object.

From the article [Implement channel-specific functionality > Create a full-fidelity Slack message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-channeldata#create-a-full-fidelity-slack-message)

> To create a full-fidelity Slack message, set the Activity object's `channelData` property to a JSON object that specifies Slack messages, Slack attachments, and/or Slack buttons.

This snippet shows an example of the channelData property for a custom Slack message.

```
"channelData": {
   "text": "Now back in stock! :tada:",
   "attachments": [
        {
            "title": "The Further Adventures of Slackbot",
            "author_name": "Stanford S. Strickland",
            "author_icon": "https://api.slack.com/img/api/homepage_custom_integrations-2x.png",
            "image_url": "http://i.imgur.com/OJkaVOI.jpg?1"
        },
        {
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "Volume",
                    "value": "1",
                    "short": true
                },
                {
                    "title": "Issue",
                    "value": "3",
                    "short": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Synopsis",
            "text": "After @episod pushed exciting changes to a devious new branch back in Issue 1, Slackbot notifies @don about an unexpected deploy..."
        },
        {
            "fallback": "Would you recommend it to customers?",
            "title": "Would you recommend it to customers?",
            "callback_id": "comic_1234_xyz",
            "color": "#3AA3E3",
            "attachment_type": "default",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "name": "recommend",
                    "text": "Recommend",
                    "type": "button",
                    "value": "recommend"
                },
                {
                    "name": "no",
                    "text": "No",
                    "type": "button",
                    "value": "bad"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For more specifics on the Slack attachment JSON structure, see:
https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, looks like Slack doesn't support the data URI I was trying to send the CSV via (as of beginning of July '17). https://twitter.com/slackapi/status/580067350357143552?lang=en . So, it looks like it might not be possible to send a dynamically created file from a slack bot currently :(